# Angular Iterate through nested form to get values

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

Am using angular 5.x. I have this JSON Data i build form already(html). I need to iterate the form elements

```
{
"_id": "TTP93E5014288850",
"productId": 10353,
"updatedAt": "2018-10-01T12:49:37.197Z",
"createdAt": "2018-05-22T06:50:29.904Z",
"name": "Le Petit-déjeuner \"Parisien\"i6060",
"arName": "فطور باريسي",
"cost": 14.66,
"category": "Breakfast packages",
"arCategory": "لائحة الفطور",
"storeCode": "dev",
"ownerId": 300200,
"prodDescription": "",
"arProdDescription": "",
"sortIndex": 57,
"url": "http://tmmmt.com/dev/TTP93E5014288850",
"__v": 0,
"offerCost": 0,
"isVatIncluded": false,
"subType": "default",
"meals": {
"packages": [],
"isMandatory": true,
"types": []
},
"isDeleted": false,
"isVerified": true,
"isTimeBased": false,
"options": [
  {
    "option": "one hot beverage of your choice",
    "arOption": " إختيارك من المشروبات الساخنة",
    "_id": "5b03bdb533e27e3a4f318acf",
    "isMandatory": true,
    "isMulti": false,
    "values": [
     {
      "value": "Cappuccino",
      "arValue": "كابوتشينو",
      "price": 0,
      "_id": "5b03bdb533e27e3a4f318ada"
     },
     {
      "value": "Espresso",
       "arValue": "اسبرسو",
       "price": 0,
       "_id": "5b03bdb533e27e3a4f318ad9"
     },
     {
       "value": "Café crème",
       "arValue": "قهوة بالكريمه",
       "price": 0,
       "_id": "5b03bdb533e27e3a4f318ad8"
     },
     {
       "value": " American coffee",
       "arValue": "قهوة اميريكيه",
       "price": 0,
       "_id": "5b03bdb533e27e3a4f318ad7"
     },
     {
       "value": "PAUL hot chocolate",
       "arValue": "شوكولاته ساخنه",
       "price": 0,
       "_id": "5b03bdb533e27e3a4f318ad6"
    },
    {
      "value": " Flat white",
      "arValue": "فلات وايت",
      "price": 0,
      "_id": "5b03bdb533e27e3a4f318ad5"
    },
    {
      "value": "Marrocchino",
      "arValue": " ماروشينو",
      "price": 0,
      "_id": "5b03bdb533e27e3a4f318ad4"
    },
    {
      "value": "Cinnamon vanilla latté",
      "arValue": " سينامون فانيلا لاتيه",
      "price": 0,
      "_id": "5b03bdb533e27e3a4f318ad3"
   },
   {
      "value": "Caramel sticky mocha",
      "arValue": "كراميل ستيكي موكا",
      "price": 0,
     "_id": "5b03bdb533e27e3a4f318ad2"
    },
    {
      "value": " PAUL vanilla black tea",
      "arValue": "شاي بول أسود بالفانيلا",
      "price": 0,
      "_id": "5b03bdb533e27e3a4f318ad0"
    }
    ]
  },
  {
   "option": "one viennoiserie of your choice",
   "arOption": " إختيارك من الفيينوازري ",
   "_id": "5b03bdb533e27e3a4f318ac3",
   "isMandatory": true,
  "isMulti": false,
  "values": [
  {
    "value": "Croissant",
    "arValue": "كرواسان",
    "price": 0,
    "_id": "5b03bdb533e27e3a4f318ace"
  },
  {
    "value": "Croissant au thym",
    "arValue": "كرواسان بالزعتر",
    "price": 0,
    "_id": "5b03bdb533e27e3a4f318acd"
  },
  {
    "value": " Croissant au fromage",
    "arValue": "كرواسان بالجبة",
    "price": 0,
    "_id": "5b03bdb533e27e3a4f318acc"
  },
  {
    "value": "Croissant aux amandes",
    "arValue": "كرواسان باللوز",
    "price": 0,
    "_id": "5b03bdb533e27e3a4f318acb"
  },
  {
    "value": " Croissant aux pistaches",
    "arValue": "كرواسان بالفستق",
    "price": 0,
    "_id": "5b03bdb533e27e3a4f318aca"
  },
  {
    "value": " Anglaise aux abricots",
    "arValue": " فطيرة كومبوت المشمش",
    "price": 0,
    "_id": "5b03bdb533e27e3a4f318ac9"
  },
  {
    "value": " Gourmandise au chocolat",
    "arValue": "غورماديز الشكولاته",
    "price": 0,
    "_id": "5b03bdb533e27e3a4f318ac8"
  },
  {
    "value": " Pain au chocolat",
    "arValue": "كرواسان الشكولاته",
    "price": 0,
    "_id": "5b03bdb533e27e3a4f318ac7"
  },
  {
    "value": "Pain aux raisins",
    "arValue": "كعكة الزبيب",
    "price": 0,
    "_id": "5b03bdb533e27e3a4f318ac6"
  },
  {
    "value": "Pain au chocolat et amandes",
    "arValue": "كرواسان الشكولاته واللوز",
    "price": 0,
    "_id": "5b03bdb533e27e3a4f318ac5"
   },
   {
     "value": " Pain au chocolat et pistaches",
     "arValue": " كرواسان الشكولاته والفستق",
     "price": 0,
     "_id": "5b03bdb533e27e3a4f318ac4"
    }
  ]
  }
 ],
 "linkType": "public",
 "pictures": [],
 "maxQuantity": 10,
 "payType": "any",
 "count": 50,
 "isAvailable": true,
 "vatPercentage": null,
 "vatCost": null,
 "baseCost": null,
 "owner": null,
 "isOffer": false,
 "isCostOffer": false,
 "isDeliveryOffer": false,
 "id": "TTP93E5014288850"
}
```

If you see that `options` key it is an array based inside that i have `values` which is also an array however i built a form with this data. Now i need to iterate through the form elements of the values alone. Am adding my angular code below.

```
initProductForm(product?: PublicProduct) {
const isOffer = product && product.offer && product.offer.startAt ? true : false;

this.productForm = this.fb.group({
  storeCode: new FormControl(
    {
      value: product && product.storeCode ? product.storeCode : this.myStore._id,
      disabled: true,
    },
    [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/\S(.*\S)?/)]
  ),
  ownerId: new FormControl(this.userPkid, Validators.required),
  name: new FormControl(product && product.name ? product.name : '', [
    Validators.required,
    Validators.pattern(/\S(.*\S)?/),
  ]),
  arName: new FormControl(product && product.arName ? product.arName : '', [
    Validators.required,
    Validators.pattern(/\S(.*\S)?/),
  ]),
  prodDescription: new FormControl(
    product && product.prodDescription ? product.prodDescription : '',
    Validators.pattern(/\S(.*\S)?/)
  ),
  arProdDescription: new FormControl(
    product && product.arProdDescription ? product.arProdDescription : '',
    Validators.pattern(/\S(.*\S)?/)
  ),
  isTimeBased: new FormControl(product && product.isTimeBased ? product.isTimeBased : false),
  startTime: new FormControl(
    product && product.menuStartTime
      ? {
          hour: moment(product.menuStartTime).hour(),
          minute: moment(product.menuStartTime).minute(),
        }
      : '',
    product && product.isTimeBased ? Validators.required : null
  ),
  endTime: new FormControl(
    product && product.menuEndTime
      ? {
          hour: moment(product.menuEndTime).hour(),
          minute: moment(product.menuEndTime).minute(),
        }
      : '',
    product && product.isTimeBased ? Validators.required : null
  ),
  menuStartTime: new FormControl(product && product.menuStartTime ? product.menuStartTime : ''),
  menuEndTime: new FormControl(product && product.menuEndTime ? product.menuEndTime : ''),
  cost: new FormControl(
    { value: product && product.cost ? product.cost : 0, disabled: isOffer },
    [Validators.required, Validators.min(0)]
  ),
  baseCost: new FormControl(
    {
      value:
        product && product.baseCost
          ? product.baseCost
          : this.calculateBaseAmount(
              product && product.cost ? product.cost : 0,
              (product && product.vatPercentage) || (product && product.vatPercentage == 0)
                ? product.vatPercentage
                : this.vatPercentage
            ),
      disabled: isOffer,
    },
    product && product.baseCost ? [(Validators.required, Validators.min(0))] : []
  ),
  category: new FormControl(product && product.category ? product.category : '', [
    Validators.required,
    Validators.pattern(/\S(.*\S)?/),
  ]),
  arCategory: new FormControl(product && product.arCategory ? product.arCategory : '', [
    Validators.required,
    Validators.pattern(/\S(.*\S)?/),
  ]),
  payType: new FormControl(
    product && product.payType ? product.payType : 'any',
    Validators.required
  ),
  imgFile: new FormControl(''),
  pictures: new FormControl(product && product.pictures ? product.pictures : ''),
  options: this.fb.array([]),
  isVatIncluded: new FormControl(product && product.vatPercentage ? true : false),
  vatPercentage: new FormControl(
    (product && product.vatPercentage) || (product && product.vatPercentage == 0)
      ? product.vatPercentage
      : this.vatPercentage
    // disabled: true,
  ),
});
```

}

Am attaching a separate form group to options key

```
initOption() {
return this.fb.group({
  option: new FormControl(''),
  isMulti: new FormControl(false),
  isMandatory: false,
  values: this.fb.array([]),
 });
}

initValue() {
 return this.fb.group({
   value: new FormControl(''),
   price: new FormControl(''),
 });
}

  addOption(option?): void {
(<FormArray>this.productForm.controls['options']).push(
  new FormGroup({
    option: new FormControl(option ? option.option : '', Validators.required),
    arOption: new FormControl(option ? option.arOption : '', Validators.required),
    isMulti: new FormControl(option ? option.isMulti : false),
    isMandatory: new FormControl(option ? option.isMandatory : false),
    values: this.fb.array([]),
  })
);

if (!option) {
  this.addValue((<FormArray>this.productForm.controls.options).length - 1);
 }
}
```

Now my question is simple all am trying to do is wanted to iterate through the values form which is inside the options form which is inside the product form. Is it possible?. I tried like this but it's not working

```
const syncBranchesControl = this.productForm.get('options');
(<FormArray>syncBranchesControl).controls.forEach((ctrl, index) => {
  console.log(ctrl);
});
```

Remember i already built the form all i want is just to iterate over the options form. Any help is appreciated thanks

Comment: What output or error are you getting with the above code?

Comment: @AmitChigadani Am not getting any error am not sure how to iterate via the form elements

Comment: Ok what does `console.log(ctrl);` print? Can you create a https://stackblitz.com/ reproducing your issue?

Comment: I know, I am late to comment on your question. But still, are you expecting a solution?

Comment: @AjayOjha No man i resolved it on the same day with help of my friend. thanks